# warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#define NUM 8

int main() {
    int i, len, sum, offset, remain;
    char bin[32];
    char hexlist[6][1] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
    char hex[NUM] = "00000000";
    int hexlen = NUM;
    while (1) {
        scanf("%s", bin);
        if (strcmp(bin, "0") == 0) {
            break;
        }
        len = strlen(bin);
        offset = 0;
        while (offset < len) {
            sum = 0;

            if (len - offset >= 4) {
                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    sum += (bin[len-1-i-offset] - '0') * pow(2, i);
                }
            }
            else {
                remain = len - offset;
                for (i = 0; i < remain; i++) {
                    sum += (bin[len-1-i-offset] - '0') * pow(2, i);
                }
            }

            if (sum > 10)
                // I got "warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"
                hex[--hexlen] = hexlist[sum%10];
            else
                hex[--hexlen] = (char)(((int)'0')+sum);

            offset += 4;
        }
        printf("%s\n", hex);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried `hex[--hexlen] = (char)hexlist[sum%10];`, but I got "warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
char hexlist[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
```

In C a character constant between double quotes indicates a string of characters, and is ended with a null character `\0`. A character constant between single quotes indicates a single character.

Comment: Yeah, or `char hexlist[] = "ABCDEF";`.

Comment: Fred Larson: You are right, and normally I would agree, but in this case an array of character constants seems more appropriate then a string.

Comment: @nightcracker, @pmg: I know. But for brevity's sake, I'd be inclined to waste the byte. Doesn't make much difference to me.

Comment: Thank you all so much. I've just learned C a week ago, I don't understand pointer clearly. Now my code works well (after I corrected the other errors).

I don't know is it appropriate, but I want to know how I add every char to an array dynamically? Not just a predefined char array `char hex[NUM] = "00000000"`.

Comment: @Vayn: it's better to post a new question rather than ask one in a comment.

Comment: @pmg I've posted new question :)

Answer (score 1):

`hexlist` is an array of arrays

```
char hexlist[6][1];
```

each element of `hexlist` is an array ... and usually references to such arrays decay to pointers. That's what is hapenning in your code: `hexlist[sum % 10]` is an object of type `char[1]` and decays to a pointer.

You then try to assign that pointer to an element of `hex`, of type `char`. The types are incompatible and after the default promotions, the compiler complains.

Comment: **No**. In many uses, arrays decay to a pointer to their first element. Read section 6 of the [`comp.lang.c` FAQ](http://c-faq.com/) ... and, once you're there, all the other sections too :)

Comment: The FAQ is nice! Thank you :D